# Reading an uploaded file in Google app engine

Tags: java, file, google-app-engine

I have a GAE application (Java) and I have to populate my datastore from an external file. Using localhost it's working fine. The problem is while deploying it I always get

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this
>   error message and the query that caused it.

This is my path file "war\WEB-INF\test.data"

Question: Is there is any change between local and distant access? 
any help?

Comment: Is there an error message and stacktrace in the logs on your  AppEngine dashboard?

Comment: Also, please show the code that you're using to load the file. AFAIK the path should rather be `"/WEB-INF/test.data"` (note the forward slashes: they work on all platforms, blackslashes only on Windows).

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur quick reply. 
I got this message "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application." in my log file but tried to change my path with only "test.data" and it worked fine after few minutes !

Comment: That's not an error, that's normal.

Answer (score 0):

We need to understand what you are executing to populate the datastore from the local file. Here are some points:

1. Assuming that you have uploaded the file in `WEB-INF` folder with name `test.data`, your file path should be `WEB-INF/test.data'
2. Are you running the code to load data via some url e.g. http://yorappid.appspot.com/loaddata or something like that? If yes, chances are that your code is taking much longer to process than the 60 seconds hard limit that AppEngine places on completing HTTP Requests. So that could be the problem where you request is not getting complete.
3. I suggest that if point 2 above is the case, please move your code to a Cron Job. They have a limit of 10 minutes and it might sufficient to load up your data. I am not sure about the amount of data that you plan to load but 10 minutes would be more than enough to load up a sufficiently large amount of data.

Hope this helps.